# Python divide list into percentages

Tags: python

I have a function that applies random colors to each set of elements defined by a percentage. In this case I have a list of 154 elements to start with, but somehow in the end  I get only 152 processed elements. Not sure why, because I am giving it 100% in total when I call the function at the end.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random

def selector(percents):
    RandomSelection = []
    mySel = cmds.ls(sl=1) # a list of elements with a total of 154
    random.shuffle(mySel)
    
    start = 0
    for cur in percents:
        end = start + cur * len(mySel) // 100
        RandomSelection.append(mySel[start:end])
        start = end
    
    print(len(mySel)) # 154
    print ( sum( [ len(listElem) for listElem in RandomSelection]) ) # 152 # why not 154?
    
    for mesh in RandomSelection:
        r = [random.random() for i in range(3)]
        cmds.polyColorPerVertex(mesh,rgb=(r[0], r[1], r[2]), cdo=1 )
    

selector([70, 10, 15, 5])
#154
#152
```

Thank you.

Comment: `end = start + cur * len(mySel) // 100` can drop up to 1 element at each iteration due to flooring.

Comment: @Julien is there anything I can do to avoid that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`end = start + cur * len(mySel) // 100` can drop up to 1 element at each iteration due to flooring.

Try this instead :

```
start = 0
cumul = 0
for cur in percents:
    cumul += cur
    end = cumul * len(mySel) // 100
    RandomSelection.append(mySel[start:end])
    start = end
```

This will still drop up to 1 at every iteration due to florring, but these drops won't accumulate (since you recompute your `end` from fresh), and at the end you are guaranteed to have an exact division, and so use up all elements.